# How can I change the look of SQL Server Management Studio based on which database I'm connected to?

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, database-connection, ssms

I'd like to modify the appearance of the query window in SQL Server Management Studio based on which database I'm currently connected to.  For example, using a yellow background for production databases.  Is there a way to do this?

Is there also a way to change the default color of the query status bar at the bottom (when a server is not selected from the Registered Servers tab)?  I'd like to also make a bright and distinct color for when I don't remember to use the Registered Servers.

Comment: see my answer below, perhaps a tad tardy, for the updated question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008 you can color code your connection without any add-ins. In SSMS 2008, go To Registered Servers and then Right-Click a server then Connection Properties tab then Select "Use Custom Color"

you can try an add-in for SQL Server 2005: [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) which has 
[Window Connection Coloring](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=1)

Comment: Wonderful.  I didn't know this was available.  It looks like the one caveat is that you must open the connection through the Registered Servers tab and not the "Connect to Server" dialog box... not a big deal.  Definitely worth the color coding.  Thanks.

Comment: KM, do you know of a way to color the default color that displays for all servers when a color for the specific server has not been chosen, or the server is connected to without using the Registered Servers tab?

Comment: @Traples, no, I can't think of a way to do that

Comment: For anyone (like me) who never even heard of Registered Servers it is in the View menu `(Ctrl + Alt + G)`

Answer (score 15):

In 2012 you can do the following, once you have done it it will remember, then you don't need to use the registered server window.

```
Set the Status Color for a Server in Object Explorer
To set a server status color in Object Explorer
1.  In Object Explorer, select the Connect button and then select Database Engine….
2.  On the Connect to Server dialog, select Options >>.
3.  Select the Use custom color check box.
4.  To select the color, select the Select… button.
5.  Select either a basic or custom color, then select OK.
6.  Fill in the rest of the connection information, and then select the Connect button.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the Registered Server colour as KM indicated.

You can also set the default colour to be whatever via Tools > Options > Text Editor > Editor Tab and Status Bar > Status Bar layour and Colors [Single server Connections].  This applies to Sql Server Managment Studio 2008.

Comment: Moving Status bar location to the top is useful too (only takes effect on new connections)